# Qual a melhor maneira de esconder funções JS visiveis ao especionar o HTML?

Tags: javascript, jsp, design-pattern

Tenho algumas funções JavaScript nas minhas paginas que anteriormente eram inseridas direto no jsp, dentro das tags `<script>`. Posteriormente alterei elas para um arquivo.js onde apenas importo as funções. Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira melhor de esconder tais funções, dificultando o usuario de achá-las.

Comment: Não, no máximo você pode usar uglify pra dificultar a leitura do javascript. Se você possui algum código que não deve ser exposto no cliente faça ele no backend e não no front.

Comment: Peça "dicas" evite palavras como "melhor" pois vai acabar na subjetividade de "baseado em opiniões" e sua pergunta pode acabar sendo fechada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não conseguirá esconder, porém, pode dificultar as coisas, minifique seu script e troque nomes explicitos por vogais ou símbolos, torne seu código ilegível por um humano. Eu utilizo o [uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) para isso